# Imprimir variables que tengan 2 o mas vocales en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito añadir a la lista palabras las palabras que tengan 2 vocales o mas de una cadena de texto pero solo imprime la primera letra

El programa que tengo es el siguiente:

```
cadena = "Tres tristes tigres comen trigo en un trigal"

palabras_cadena = cadena.split(" ")

vocales = 'aeiou'

palabras = []

total = 0

for i in range(len(palabras_cadena)):
    for j in range(len(vocales)):
        if vocales[j] in palabras_cadena[i]:
            total += 1

        for x in palabras_cadena[i]:
            if total == 2:
                palabras.append(palabras_cadena[i])
            

print(palabras)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Otra solución:

```
cadena = "Tres tristes tigres comen trigo en un trigal"
resultado = []
for palabra in cadena.split():
    if len([x for x in palabra if x in "aeiou"]) >= 2:
        resultado.append(palabra)
print(resultado)
```

El primer `for` divide la cadena en palabras y la recorre una por una.

Dentro de ese `for`, usamos una comprensión de lista para generar una lista con las vocales de cada palabra. Si el largo de esa lista es mayor o igual a dos, la agregamos a la lista en formación.

Finalmente, imprimimos la lista con las palabras encontradas.

Answer (score 0):

Estás construyendo los bucles mal. Comprueba lo que te da `range(len(palabras_cadena))`

Siguiendo la lógica que quieres aplicar sería algo así:

```
for palabra in palabras_cadena:
    total = 0
    for vocal in vocales:
        if vocal in palabra:
            total += 1
    # Edit: Aqui es >= xq son dos vocales o mas, no exactamente 2
    if total >= 2:
        palabras.append(palabra)
```

Comment: puedes meter el segundo `if` dentro del segundo `for` y agregar un `break` después del `append` así te evitas tener que terminar de iterar cunado ya se ha cumplido la condición

Comment: Totalmente, era por dejar la lógica que tenía el OP. Realmente la opción que plantea no es óptima porque no detecta si una vocal de repite, por poner un ejemplo.